# Using multiple conditions in ? : statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

In need to check three conditions and assign a value to a variable according the condition.

```
if(a =="z1"){
   b = "one";
} else if(a =="z2"){
   b = "two";
} else if(a =="z3"){
   b = "three";
}
```

Is it possible to do it in JavaScript using ? : statement to make it as a single line code

Comment: ___Java !== JavaScript___

Comment: `b=['one','two','three'][a[1]-1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use convert it to [Conditional(ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
var a = "z3";
var b = a == "z1" ? "one" : a == "z2" ? "two" : a == "z3" ? "three" : "" ;

console.log(b);
```

---

**FYI :** For a better readability, I would suggest using `if...else` statement or use `switch` statement . Although you need to use parenthesis for nested ternary operator for avoiding problems in case complex operations.

Comment: But you should not!

Comment: @Rayon :  why not?

Comment: 1) Unnecessary 2) Not-Readable 3) No advantage over conventional `if-else` condition...

Comment: @Rayon : for reducing number of char it's helpfull

Comment: It is one step closer to minification. :P

Comment: @zer00ne : may be that's his need ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var b = (a =="z1") ? "one" : ((a =="z2") ?"two":(a =="z3")?"three":null);
```

Don't forget that it's tough to read to read this quickly.
It's quite ok to use for one if else block.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this things:

b=( a=="z1"?"one":(a =="z2"? "two":(a =="z3"?"three":undefined)))

Answer (score 1):

```
var b = a == "z1" ? "one" : ( a == "z2" ? "two" : ( a == "z3" ? "three" : undefined ) ) ;
```

```js
a = "z1"

alert(a == "z1" ? "one" : ( a == "z2" ? "two" : ( a == "z3" ? "three" : undefined ) ) );

a = "z2"

alert(a == "z1" ? "one" : ( a == "z2" ? "two" : ( a == "z3" ? "three" : undefined ) ) );

a = "z3"

alert(a == "z1" ? "one" : ( a == "z2" ? "two" : ( a == "z3" ? "three" : undefined ) ) );

a = "z4"

alert(a == "z1" ? "one" : ( a == "z2" ? "two" : ( a == "z3" ? "three" : undefined ) ) );
```